# str_replace not replacing <br> with \r\n but \\r\\n

Tags: php, textbox, str-replace

Im getting result `$code` from API and using **str_replace** to translate/replace results.
In the script below I need to replace `<br>` with `\r\n` so I can show the results in a textbox but the result Im getting is: `\\r\\n` instead of `\r\n`

My script:

```
$code = 'IMEI : 012417003071XXX<br>Serial : 8503702RAXX<br>';

$olddata = array('IMEI : ', '<br>', 'Serial : ');
$newdata = array('IMEI: ', '\r\n', 'Serial: ');

$newcode = str_replace($olddata, $newdata, $code);

$result['imeireport'] = $newcode;
echo json_encode($result);
```

The result I get:

```
{"imeireport":"\r\n\r\n\r\nIMEI: 012417003071XXX\\r\\nSerial: 8503702RAXX\\r\\n"}
```

I need to get rid of `\r\n\r\n\r\n` (before IMEI:) and replace `\\r\\n` with `\r\n`

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try using double quotes (") rather than single quotes (') for the `\r\n`.

Comment: @Mave you really should put that comment into an answer!

Comment: Haha, done that. Cheers, glad it worked out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes (") rather than single quotes (') for regex stuff (like `\r\n`):

```
str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $string);
```